# Binarization and Background Filtering in opencv

Tags: opencv, image-processing, ocr, tesseract

Shortly, I want to make the pre-processing procedures before OCR with the suggestion comes from [ABBYY 's technology](http://www.abbyy-developers.eu/en:tech:insideocr:adaptive_binarisation). There are two parts in article:

- **Background Filtering**: separate text strings from background.
  [image]
- **Adaptive Binarization**: make lines and words will be correctly detected and higher recognition accuracy will be reached. And they try to impact on characters.
  [image]
  [image]

I wonder are there any ways to achieve them by using `opencv`? Any suggestions or sample codes would be appreciated.

Comment: looks like some kind of adaptive thresholding: try http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#adaptivethreshold

Comment: @Micka I think adaptive thresholding isn't good enough for most cases, I tried it and got the bad results, it make the dots area in images and cover the characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would encourage you to use this code: http://liris.cnrs.fr/christian.wolf/software/binarize/
In particular wolf's binarization, it works really well in practice and it needs very little change to c++ code if you want to use it with opencv. Basically you have to pass the pointer to your image data to this function.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a couple of papers, hope it'll be useful:

Paper from XEROX: http://www.xrce.xerox.com/content/download/6708/51560/file/Binarising-camera-images-for-OCR.pdf

And another good paper about image preprocessing for ocr: http://wbieniec.kis.p.lodz.pl/research/files/07_memstech_ocr.pdf

Comment: Thanks, actually I have read many books and got some advice, then I try to apply many processing methods for my app but they aren't cover most cases because my app uses automatically pre-processing procedures for all images