# TesserAct and OpenCV

Tags: ios, opencv, tesseract

I just downloaded and managed to run both the tesseract ocr and openCV separately in two different projects. (The new opencv and tesseract compatible with iOS 7)

I want to include them in a single project(target).

The problem is OpenCV need to use libc++ as C++ Standard Library. While TesserAct needs to use Compiler Default as the C++ Standard Library.

Is there a way to set both of them and tell the Xcode to use libc++ for opencv and Compiler Default for tesseract?

Comment: This problem has been answered already. Refer to this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16323316/tesseract-ocr-3-02-with-libc)

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this example](https://github.com/pablosproject/iPhone-OCR-Tesseract-and-OpenCV). I tried image enhancement by `OpenCV` in this project and I think it is quite good.

Comment: Results of codes on your link is very bad. All IOS tesseract samples on Github have bad results.

Comment: @CanÜrek surely you can't use this code to get good result without changing anything. Image processing for OCR isn't easy as it does. You can try my other question to apply binarization before OCR: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21696386/binarization-and-background-filtering-in-opencv

Comment: Thanks for link. But Im working on OCR project for IOS for a month. And i cant improve my results. Pre-processing is big problem for me.

Comment: @CanÜrek you know what? I used to work on this OCR project for a long time and I got a good result (not perfect, but still good) by trying many ways. Look at this library (in my previous accept answer) http://liris.cnrs.fr/christian.wolf/software/binarize/ and try your own with correct parameters (test on many cases until you get the aspect result). I can only help you like this. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You are probably talking about like that. I will share my experiences when i will completely success OCR :)

```
cv::vector<cv::Mat> produceThresholds(const cv::Mat img_gray) {
const int THRESHOLD_COUNT = 4;
// Mat img_equalized = equalizeBrightness(img_gray);

cv::vector<cv::Mat> thresholds;

for (int i = 0; i < THRESHOLD_COUNT; i++)
    thresholds.push_back(cv::Mat(img_gray.size(), CV_8U));

int i = 0;

// Adaptive
// adaptiveThreshold(img_gray, thresholds[i++], 255, ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,
// THRESH_BINARY_INV , 7, 3);
// adaptiveThreshold(img_gray, thresholds[i++], 255, ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,
// THRESH_BINARY_INV , 13, 3);
// adaptiveThreshold(img_gray, thresholds[i++], 255, ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,
// THRESH_BINARY_INV , 17, 3);

// Wolf
int k = 0, win = 18;
// NiblackSauvolaWolfJolion (img_gray, thresholds[i++], WOLFJOLION, win, win,
// 0.05 + (k * 0.35));
// bitwise_not(thresholds[i-1], thresholds[i-1]);
NiblackSauvolaWolfJolion(img_gray, thresholds[i++], WOLFJOLION, win, win,
                         0.05 + (k * 0.35));
//bitwise_not(thresholds[i - 1], thresholds[i - 1]);

k = 1;
win = 22;
NiblackSauvolaWolfJolion(img_gray, thresholds[i++], WOLFJOLION, win, win,
                         0.05 + (k * 0.35));
//bitwise_not(thresholds[i - 1], thresholds[i - 1]);
// NiblackSauvolaWolfJolion (img_gray, thresholds[i++], WOLFJOLION, win, win,
// 0.05 + (k * 0.35));
// bitwise_not(thresholds[i-1], thresholds[i-1]);

// Sauvola
k = 1;
NiblackSauvolaWolfJolion(img_gray, thresholds[i++], SAUVOLA, 12, 12,
                         0.18 * k);
bitwise_not(thresholds[i - 1], thresholds[i - 1]);
k = 2;
NiblackSauvolaWolfJolion(img_gray, thresholds[i++], SAUVOLA, 12, 12,
                         0.18 * k);
//bitwise_not(thresholds[i - 1], thresholds[i - 1]);

return thresholds;
// threshold(img_equalized, img_threshold, 100, 255, THRESH_BINARY);
}
```